# Any value in the list - in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I need to pull all values where the request type is any of the ones I have on the list.

```
from v in ctx.vEmailSents
where  v.RequestType_ID == reqTypeID
group v by v.SentToLab_ID into g
select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateSent).FirstOrDefault() into lastV
  select new
  {
    ClaimID = lastV.Claim_ID,
  };
```

`reqTypeID` is of type `List<int>`.

How can I use it in Linq to get all records that are in that list?

Comment: I always know that it's Linq-To-Sql when people don't care to format their code.

Comment: i clicked the code button, not sure how else i need to format it. thanks for updating my post!

Comment: You must select then click the code button.

Comment: I think the issue was the mass of whitespace before each line!

Comment: Where is the `request` type, do you really have a `List<int>` named `reqTypeID`, what are you aksing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
where requestTypes.Contains(v.RequestType_ID)
```

`requestTypes` would be the list you talked about.